# FileNotFoundError when reading in JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load my train emotion from a JSON file but getting below error.

**Code**

```py
# load JSON and create the model
json_file = open('model/emotion_model.json', 'r') 
loaded_model_json = json_file.read() 
json_file.close() 
emotion_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

**Error**

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 7
> 8 # load JSON and create the model
> ----> 9 json_file = open('model/emotion_model.json', 'r')
> 10 loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
> 11 json_file.close()
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'model/emotion_model.json'

Comment: I removed the irrelevant tags since issue really involves reading a JSON file regardless of its content and use.

Comment: Please explain *how* you are running this code. At command line? In an IDE? Check current working directory. Be sure calling script is at the relative level to read JSON.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, please i'm running it on goggle colab